# How to open Location screen, specifically Location permission screen where you select between Always, When in Use, Never?

Tags: ios, settings, url-scheme

The following piece of code opens the apps settings screen:

```
NSURL *appSettingsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appSettingsUrl];
```

Is it possible to open the location authorization (permissions) screen. The screen where there's a list of three items Always, When in Use, Never?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to open it. However other developers have discovered that the following URL may work: `URL(string: "App-prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES")`. As this is not documented it may not pass store review if that is your purpose.